# C: Storing line from .txt file into a 2d array

Tags: c, string, file-io

I have a read function but the last line repeats 3 more times

```
 void read()
 {
    FILE *file;
    char line[50];
    int numProgs = 0;
    char* programs[50];
    int i = 0;
    file = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line, 50, file) != NULL) {
       printf("%s", line);
       programs[i]=line; 
       i++;
       numProgs++;
     }

    int j = 0;
    for (j=0 ; j<numProgs; j++) {
      printf("\n%s", programs[j]);
    }

     fclose(file);
}
```

My testing.txt doc is filled with 3 lines (but it can be more)

```
Jane Smith   123 blue jay st    123-123-3312
John Doe    12 blue st    321-222-1131
Amy White    431 yellow st    +1-23-738-2912
```

When I run my read function however, it shows this

```
Jane Smith   123 blue jay st    123-123-3312
John Doe    12 blue st    321-222-1131
Amy White    431 yellow st    +1-23-738-2912
Amy White    431 yellow st    +1-23-738-2912
Amy White    431 yellow st    +1-23-738-2912
```

i can't seem to figure it out why it's repeating the last line. thanks!

Comment: Because you don't copy line content, each read override it.

Comment: Is there any reason you need both 'numProgs' and 'i'?  They appear to be initialized to the same value (0), and both get incremented at the same time.  I know that doesn't solve your problem, but you should reduce the complexity of your code, and it will make bugs easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace

```
programs[i] = line;
```

with

```
programs[i] = strdup(line);
```

Comment: a warning* : warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’

Answer (score 1):

With `strdup` for example:

```
FILE *file;
char line[50];
int numProgs = 0;
char* programs[50];
file = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
while(fgets(line, 50, file) && numProgs < 50) {
    printf("%s", line);
    programs[numProgs++;] = strdup(line);
}

for (int j  =0 ; j < numProgs; j++) {
    printf("\n%s", programs[j]);
    free(programs[j]);
}

fclose(file);
```